# Is it safe to use a macrium disk image to transfer all my data between identical laptops?

Tags: windows, laptop, backup, disk-image, macrium

I recently bought a new laptop and after using it for a while I have noticed a fault. I have made a warranty claim and will be receiving an identical model in a few days.

My original laptop obviously has all my data, configurations and programs on it and I would like everything on this laptop to be on the replacement.

I have read online that using disk images between different machines can cause problems due to conflicting hardware. However, since both these machines are identical, will there be any issues (given I deactivate my windows license on my current machine to avoid any activation issues)?

Comment: If you restore an image of a Windows installation from difference machine than the target machine you will have to change the license key for that new separate installation. You will have to research if the software you plan to use supports restoring an image to different hardware. You cannot actually deactivated OEM licenses since they are not transferable.

Comment: @Ramhound I used a pro key to change my licence, will this still be an issue?

Comment: You will have to change the license key regardless.